# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e'

Tags: c#, visual-studio, bluetooth

I am trying to run this code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.Devices.Bluetooth;
using Windows.Devices.Enumeration;

namespace Bluetooth_sharp
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            
            // Query for extra properties you want returned
            string[] requestedProperties = { "System.Devices.Aep.DeviceAddress", "System.Devices.Aep.IsConnected" };

            DeviceWatcher deviceWatcher =
                        DeviceInformation.CreateWatcher(
                                BluetoothLEDevice.GetDeviceSelectorFromPairingState(false),
                                requestedProperties,
                                DeviceInformationKind.AssociationEndpoint);

            // Register event handlers before starting the watcher.
            // Added, Updated and Removed are required to get all nearby devices
            deviceWatcher.Added += DeviceWatcher_Added;
            deviceWatcher.Updated += DeviceWatcher_Updated;
            deviceWatcher.Removed += DeviceWatcher_Removed;

            // EnumerationCompleted and Stopped are optional to implement.
            deviceWatcher.EnumerationCompleted += DeviceWatcher_EnumerationCompleted;
            deviceWatcher.Stopped += DeviceWatcher_Stopped;

            // Start the watcher.
            deviceWatcher.Start();

            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Press any key . . .");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }

        private static void DeviceWatcher_Stopped(DeviceWatcher sender, object args)
        {
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        private static void DeviceWatcher_EnumerationCompleted(DeviceWatcher sender, object args)
        {
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        private static void DeviceWatcher_Removed(DeviceWatcher sender, DeviceInformationUpdate args)
        {
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        private static void DeviceWatcher_Updated(DeviceWatcher sender, DeviceInformationUpdate args)
        {
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        private static void DeviceWatcher_Added(DeviceWatcher sender, DeviceInformation args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(args.Name);
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

}
```

This is sample code which I got from: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/gatt-client

But when I execute it I get the following error:

```
'Bluetooth-sharp.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Bluetooth-sharp.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\elect\source\repos\Bluetooth-sharp\Bluetooth-sharp\bin\Debug\Bluetooth-sharp.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'Bluetooth-sharp.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Bluetooth-sharp.exe): Loaded 'C:\windows\SysNative\WinMetadata\Windows.Devices.winmd'. Module was built without symbols.
'Bluetooth-sharp.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Bluetooth-sharp.exe): Loaded 'C:\Users\elect\source\repos\Bluetooth-sharp\Bluetooth-sharp\bin\Debug\System.Runtime.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in Unknown Module.
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

The program '[10840] Bluetooth-sharp.exe' has exited with code 4294967295 (0xffffffff).
```

I was following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CozmqN_iwNs&t=356s&ab_channel=CornelHuman), but he didn't encounter this error.
One thing I did differently is that his *System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll* is in *C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5*, while I got mine from *C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\runtime.win10-arm.microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.2.14\runtimes\win10-arm\lib\uap10.0.15138* because I only had XML files in the other folder.

Nothing I could find with Google was able to fix the problem.

Comment: System.Private.CoreLib is .Net core main runtime library !! Is this project in .Net core ?

Comment: I've used the console app (.NET Framework) preset in accordance with the linked tutorial since he used the same one

Answer (score 0):

In your issue, what happened was that .NET native compilation was skipped in storage, resulting in an invalid bundle because the declared dependencies did not match the contents of the bundle. You need to recheck the version of the dependencies you are using. Also, I noticed that "The program '[10840] Bluetooth-sharp.exe' has exited with code 4294967295 (0xffffffff)." This is because the corresponding file was not found, you'd better change to the same path as your sample code.